# How to precompile typescript when packaging with electron-forge

Tags: reactjs, performance, typescript, electron, electron-forge

The app starts with a blank screen for a while before the app really loads

I'm using electron-forge's [react-typescript template](https://electronforge.io/templates).

I can make a `dmg` or `deb` file successfully, but I noticed when I run the packaged app, there will be a blank screen for a while before the app actually load especially the first time

I checked the distributable file and found the whole source code inside it, so I guess it's because it has to compile `typescript` every time?

Then how to "precompile" my source code and use that to make a distributable app?

update:
Since the project was developed by other colleague, I just found out this project is using electron-compile to compile it on the fly, maybe the solution has something to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I checked the distributable file and found the whole source code inside it, so I guess it's because it has to compile typescript every time?

This is not true. Current stable uses `electron-prebuilt-compile` (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/blob/1709af0bc53bd962466dd2025672b95f2e9399cc/packages/api/core/src/util/electron-version.ts#L6) which creates precompiled cache for typescript files for packaging time. Typescript source is only needed for module resolution in actual filesystem.

> there will be a blank screen for a while before the app actually load especially the first time

This requires profiling application itself to find out what is happening in meanwhile. It is possible module resolution takes long or either any js execution time's blocking, but can't tell without profiling it.

Comment: Thanks for stopping me dig further in the wrong direction, I've never profiled anything before, I'll give it a shot anyway